# Steam Install problems 14.04 LTS

Tags: steam

I've got a new pc yesterday, installed 14.04lts and had some problems with my graphics card driver (now fixed I believe). Now I've tried installing steam through various methods and can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Gtx 950
i7 4790k

Comment: what errors are you getting when you try to install, how are you trying to install?  there is an issue when using the Ubuntu Software Center that causes the install to fail when you install 14.04.03(the only version that you can download from the Ubuntu site); it tries to pull some of the wrong packages......Please include more info to get any usable answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clear any remains of steam you have installed
   `sudo apt-get purge steam`
2. Install Steam
   `sudo apt-get install steam`
3. Click start key (or click search icon) and type in "steam"

---

If that does not work try the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge stream
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install Steam
```

This should install any 32 bit libraries needed (although this should be done automatically by `sudo apt-get install steam` if needed.

---

- Let us know what the errors are.

Comment: Ah thank you guys! I Just put your command lines in and it worked nicely!

Answer (score 0):

Install steam via steam's [hompage](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) will work with file .deb.

- 1. Download file from [hompage](http://store.steampowered.com/about/)
- 2. Right-click file click .deb and install via Ubuntu software center